# How I specified the SpreadsheetApp.open is not working? Why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been chasing my own tail over this simple `Google Apps Script function`.  I get this error

> "Cannot find method open(string). (line 4, file "Code")" on the line below where SpreadsheetApp.open is when i try to run the function:

```
function JackTest5() { 
  var ResponsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open("Jack TEST (Responses)");
  var sheet = (spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());
}
```

Please advise.  What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets and Google Drive don't use filenames / filepaths to uniquely identify files.

[SpreadsheetApp.open(file)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile) requires an [file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) object as argument, instead use

See [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to learn about the available methods and the required arguments.